# python replacing certain letters/words in string using iteritems()

Tags: python

so i have the code which replaces certain letters/words in strings with others

```
c = {"u":"i", "c":"see", "me":"you"}

for a,b in c.iteritems():
        response = response.replace(a,b)
```

this turns `["u c me"]` into `["i see you"]`
but also turns `["uncalled"]` into `["inseealled"]`

I only want to change the first string, but leave the second string the same

is there a way around this?

Comment: Well, what is `c` there? Please post a compilable code.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> d = {"u":"i", "c":"see", "me":"you"}
>>> ' '.join(d.get(word, word) for word in "u c me".split())
'i see you'
>>> ' '.join(d.get(word, word) for word in "uncalled".split())
'uncalled'
```

---

```
>>> d = {'me': 'you', 'c': 'see', 'u': 'i', 'are': 'am'}
>>> ' '.join(d.get(word, word) for word in "u are big".split())
'i am big'
>>> ' '.join(d.get(word, word) for word in "unique".split())
'unique'
```

Comment: is there a way to change this code so I can enter a random word starting with u (for example "unique") and it'll stay "unique" but if i enter "u are big" it'll change to "i am big"?

Comment: but is there a way without including the strings "u are big" and "unique" in the code? thanks

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly perfect but if there is only a few you wish to replace you could include spaces when searching for the letters ie:

```
b = {"u ":"i", "c ":"see", "me ":"you"," u ":"i", " c ":"see", " me ":"you",
     " u":"i", " c":"see", "me ":"you"}
```

Comment: That's not valid python syntax.